# Split View in adobe flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, adobe, uisplitviewcontroller

I have four views:
1.SplitView (main view)
2.SplitViewHomeView(root Panel)
3.SimpleView(Right panel)
4.Details(child of Right Panel View).
I am trying to accomplish the split view as in Ipad in adobe flex mobile.But unable to connect the root panel to right panel...Can any one suggest the path to me.My Code is below

Split View
**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <s:ViewNavigator id="MainView" left="0" width="300" height="748" firstView="views.SplitViewHomeView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="MainView1" left="301" width="732" height="748" firstView="views.SimpleView"/>

</s:Application>
```

**
SplitViewHomeView
**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Root View"
        creationComplete="srv.send()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="srv" url="assets/employees.xml"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
            dataProvider="{srv.lastResult.list.employee}">

        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer
                    label="{data.Name} {data.Founder}"
                    messageField="title"/>
            </fx:Component>

        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>

</s:View>
```

**
Simple View
**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home View"
        creationComplete="srv.send()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="srv" url="assets/employees.xml"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
            dataProvider="{srv.lastResult.list.employee}"
            change="navigator.pushView(Details, list.selectedItem)">
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:IconItemRenderer
                    label="{data.Name} {data.Founder}"
                    messageField="title"/>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>
```

**
DetailsView
**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        title="Details">

    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" gap="12">
        <s:Image source="assets/pics/{data.picture}"/>
        <s:VGroup>

        </s:VGroup>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button label="Back" click="navigator.popToFirstView()"/>
    </s:navigationContent>


</s:View>
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Check out the open source [eskimo library](http://e-skimo.com/)

Download the zip and look for the `SplitViewApplication.as` or `SplitView.as`
These components will do exactly what you are looking for.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Dennis...can you please elaborate of how it should be used ?

Comment: There is .fxp file included in the zip called TourDeEskimo, it is basically a Flash Builder project showcasing all features of eskimo in which you can view source.
That should get you going.

Comment: hi...Split View is now supported in Adobe Flex 4.6...they have provided standard controllers...it self...

Comment: Indeed, you should be using that instead